# A Work Permit for USA

Tags: work

I have an employee that has a passport from India, is a permanent residency status in Canada. The employee will need to travel to the US for work. What would my letter request need to say to obtain a travel Visa?

Comment: It depends on the specific visa for which the employee is applying, which in turn depends on the specific activities to be undertaken in the US, and possibly on the planned duration of stay in the US.

Comment: You need to share more details here. Is the employee moving to US to work for your US company? Or just visiting - in this case, for how long, and which entity (US or Canadian) covers the costs of the trip and pays his salary during the trip?